# styled component delay setting property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I'm new to [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com)

I have a "dumb" *React* "component" which is a **Loader** and I would like to show it after some delay. I was thinking to set its `opacity` or `display` property after a certain amount of time had passed, but I'm not sure how to do that.

If that's not possible, then perhaps adding or removing a class would serve as well (with same delay) but again, I don't know how to do that on a *stateless* component

Thanks

Comment: I've been working with styled-components for about a month - not sure they would solve this problem specifically. Your dump component might need to get smarter, so consider some control in it to dynamically apply a class after a delay to cause the loader to show

Comment: I would actually prefer wrapping it in a another Component which will delay its rendering than making it "smart".

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the state of the parent to decide when the Loader should be rendered.

Following code should all be in the parent component that renders the Loader.

In the constructor initialise the state

```
this.state = {showLoader: false}
```

Define a function (in the class) to show the loader component. By defining it as an arrow function you auto bind it to the class so we have no problems passing it as a callback.

```
showLoader = () => {
    this.setState({ showLoader: true })
}
```

In componentDidMount set a timeout for when you want the Loader to render, and pass the showLoader function as a callback. In this example it’ll be called after 1000ms.

```
componentDidMount() {
   setTimeout(this.showLoader, 1000)
}
```

In the render function, only render Loader if that state is set to true

```
render() {
   const { showLoader } = this.state

   return (
      <div>
         ... other stuff
         {showLoader && <Loader \>}
      <\div>
   )
}
```

Hope that helps!!

**edit:**

If you wanted to use some transition, instead of conditionally rendering the Loader component pass it the showLoader state as a prop and use that to conditionally add a class.

Parent render function: same as before excerpt for the line that renders the Loader

```
<Loader show={showLoader} \>
```

In the child render, assuming this div wraps rest of the markup

```
<div className={this.props.show ? ‘show’ : ‘’} \>
```

Then if the div starts with opacity 0 and has a transition: opacity 1s property (change the time for whatever fits your usage) then the ‘show’ class would just need to add opacity 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure css route, you can add keyframes and animation to the loader component.

```
animation: fade-in 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

where the second parameter in `animation` is the delay.  You can combine this with some conditional rendering in your jsx to had a delay on your animation without the use of settimeout

Comment: That my friend, trust me I know how to do and wouldn't ask :)